# SQL create new column based on number of instances in different column

Tags: sql

I want to create a new columns based on values in another column.

I have SQL database with below table:

```
   col1 col2
    2    H
    2    H1
    3    J
    3    J1
    3    J2
```

I try to transpose into the following:

```
   col1 col2 col_new1  col_new2 
    2    H      H1
    3    J      J1        J2
```

I use SQL report so can not define any variables or functions. Is there any CASE combination I could use?

Comment: What RDBMS? MySQL, SQL Server, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly trickier than a simple pivot.  Assuming you have at most three columns to pivot, you can do:

```
select col1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then col2 end) as col2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then col2 end) as col2_new1
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then col2 end) as col2_new2
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by col1;
```

If you don't know the number of columns you want in the result set, then you cannot use a simple `select`.  You need to use dynamic SQL.